# Django - How to automatically change the value by selecting different options

Tags: python, django

I'm quite noob on jquery, so i'm wondering if there's any method to meet my needs.

I've got a select box with different options and how to change the value automatically by clicking different values in the select box?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3pGe.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRfwZ.png)

Which means if i choose the value 1 in the first box, the second box value is 1, and it will turn to 2 automatically by select another option in the first box. How to meet my needs?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use temporary view. Send dropdown id to this view by using jquery.

```
<select onchange="render_new_fields()"> {# options #} </select>
<div class="fields-to-update">
    {# keep-blank #}
</div>
```

```
function render_new_fields(){
    $(.ajax){
        url: '{{ url-of-temporary-view }}'.
        success: function (result){
            $('.fields-to-update').html(result)
        }
    }
}
```

send new form from temporary-view and render template with values for fields

someting like this should be in your temp-template.html

```
{# your-all-three-fields #}
```